# Network scanner on Python

Tags: python, oop, nmap, port-scanning, network-scan

I am making a network scanner python project and have created below code by looking through youtube learning. But it is not working and giving an error. here is the code-

```
import nmap
 class network(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ip = input("Enter default IP address 10.10.1.1 10.10.0.1 ")
        self.ip = ip

    def networkscanner(self):
        if len(self.ip) == 0:
            network = '10.10.1.1/24'
        else:
            network = self.ip + '/24'

    print("Start scanning please wait....")

    nm = nmap.Portscanner()
    nm.scan(hosts=network, arguments='-sn')
    hosts_list = [(x, nm[x]['status']['state']) for x in nm.all_hosts()]
    for host, status, in hosts_list:
        print("host \t{}".format(host))

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        D = network()
        D.networkscanner()
```

What I have understood that nmap doesn't have portscanner attributes but not sure though. I have imported python-nmap too and tried but still not working. Can anyone point me to the right direction please?

Comment: *giving an error* What error did you get? What was description of that error?

Comment: oops! here it is -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/PycharmProjects/networkscanner/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    class network(object):
  File "/home/kali/PycharmProjects/networkscanner/main.py", line 15, in network
    nm = nmap.Portscanner()
AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'Portscanner'

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the correct call would be:

```
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

You have a lower case "s" instead of an upper case.

https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out but no , still the same error showing

Comment: So when you changed it to "nm = nmap.PortScanner()", you still get the error of "network nm = nmap.Portscanner() AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'Portscanner"? Or is it a new error?

Comment: No its a same error mentioned above   nm = nmap.PortScanner()
AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have managed to run the above code without any error, here are few things I did :

1. Uninstall both nmap and python-nmap and re installed python-nmap
2. correct some of the spelling and indentations

and voila! It worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).